# Read XML from php generated webpage

Tags: php, xml, soap

I need to read the content of a XML file that I receive from a web service.

When i see the source code of my generated page I can see this:
http://pastebin.com/hnnzAcPH

I see Id: string(398) "" in my webpage, but not the xml, how can I access and read the xml tag SOAP:Body?

Comment: Of course you dont see the XML. Its evaluated by your browser. The string(398) tells you that its there though. If you want to process it use an XML parser or the SOAP Client extension. Also note that we already have a number of questions asking how to read SOAP responses so you are encouraged to use the Search function.

Comment: what about the php file??? it looks like you'r inspecting the variable Id

Comment: so How to read that XML that is inside my webpage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+soap+response+body+php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself, in my case:

```
$xml = $XmlArray->children("soap", true)->Body->children();
```